# configure rhino in javascript Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, mozilla, rhino

i want to Debug my js codes in Eclipse.
how to setup Mozilla rhino in Eclipse...
(step by step guide.

Comment: Have you succeeded and share answer?

Comment: Just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312766/debug-javascript-within-eclipse-using-rhino

Comment: There is no instruction how to set up. I cannot find update site searching Internet for 1 hour.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using embedded Rhino I would use the debugger provided with the Rhino shell in the tools folder.

Check out the source code and browse to the main.java file in the debugger tool. Use that as a template to create your code to start the debugger in your javascript code.

As for using Eclipse to debug an embedded Rhino application I have heard of people doing it but I don't think that it would be worth the trouble.